# Calling perl script within a bash "while" statement

Tags: bash

I'd like help with calling a perl script from within the while loop of a bash script. An extract of my script is:

```
touch $OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT_XML_PARSE

while read -r LINE; do
   perl newscript.pl "$LINE" >> $OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT_XML_PARSE
done < $OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT_FILENAME_LIST
```

The file $OUTPUT_FILENAME_LIST contains a list of filenames each of which the Perl script uses as input argument to open and modify the data and writes the output to $OUTPUT_XML_PARSE.

The error when i run the program is "Can't open perl script "IDOCXML_parse.pl": A file or directory in the path name does not exist.". The perl script is in the same directory as the bash script, so I'm not sure why this is the case. Please advise.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES. Someday you'll use `PATH=...` and break your script.

Comment: To learn more about shell variable naming standards, see [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/6862601).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are invoking your script like `/path/to/myscript.sh` from some directory other than /path/to.

Try

```
perl "$(dirname "$0")/IDOCXML_parse.pl" ...
```

or

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
while read ...; do perl ./IDOCXML_parse.pl ...
```

Also, bash while-read loops are really slow. Try this

```
xargs -I X -L 1 perl ./IDOCXML_parse.pl X < input.file > output.file
```

or rewrite the perl script to accept the input file-of-filenames and let perl iterate over it.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I tried your code that does not involve the while loop, that resulted in the error - "A file or directory in the path name does not exist. at /home/kal/IDOCXML_parse.pl line 22
 at /home/kal/IDOCXML_parse.pl line 22", and line 22 is `$twig->parsefile( $ARGV[0] );` . How can i change your statement in a way that the filename is passed as an **argument**  to the perl script?

Comment: Apparently the filenames in the input file do not have absolute paths. Fix that if you can. Otherwise you have to `cd` to the directory containing those files and call the perl script using an absolute path